# For loop in .map React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, antd

I'm having trouble while trying to create a for-loop in a .map function.

I am using 'Reactjs' and 'Antd'.

I have a getSubMenu function which contains the following code:

```
getSubMenu = (menuItem: any) => {
        let subMenus;
        if (menuItem.subMenu.length > 0) {
            let subMenu = [];
            for (let x = 0; x < menuItem.subMenu.length; x++) {
                subMenu.push(menuItem.subMenu[x]);
                this.getSubMenu(menuItem.subMenu[x]);
            }
                subMenus = <>
                    <Menu>
                    {subMenu.map((subMenu: any) =>
                    <SubMenu key={subMenu.id} title={subMenu.name}>
                        //THE FOR-LOOP SHOULD BE POSITIONED RIGHT HERE\\
                    </SubMenu>
                    )}
                    </Menu>
                </>
        }
```

I want the submenu for-loop to be repeated until the last submenu of each submenu has been returned.

I tried the following, but this resulted in typing the submenus hardcoded anyway:

```
    getSubMenu = (menuItem: any) => {
        let subMenus;
        if (menuItem.subMenu.length > 0) {
            let subMenu = [];
            for (let x = 0; x < menuItem.subMenu.length; x++) {
                subMenu.push(menuItem.subMenu[x]);
                this.getSubMenu(menuItem.subMenu[x]);
            }
                subMenus = <>
                    <Menu>
                    {subMenu.map((subMenu: any) =>
                    <SubMenu key={subMenu.id} title={subMenu.name}>
                        {subMenu.subMenu.map((subMenu: any) =>
                        <SubMenu key={subMenu.id} title={subMenu.name}>
                            {subMenu.subMenu.map((subMenu: any) =>
                                <SubMenu key={subMenu.id} title={subMenu.name}>
                                    {subMenu.subMenu.map((subMenu: any) =>
                                        <SubMenu key={subMenu.id} title={subMenu.name}>
                                            ...
                                        </SubMenu>
                                    )}
                                </SubMenu>
                            )}
                        </SubMenu>
                        )}
                    </SubMenu>
                    )}
                    </Menu>
                </>
        }
```

Is there any way I could make a loop to acquire all submenus without having to do it hardcoded?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the for loop for? You might be able to just use another map.

Comment: I think this article may help you come up with a better design https://dev.to/jsmanifest/create-a-modern-dynamic-sidebar-menu-in-react-using-recursion-36eo?utm_campaign=React%2BNewsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_source=React_Newsletter_187

Comment: I want the for-loop to replace all the duplicated code as shown in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a for loop in a .map, but you can't put a for loop directly into JSX.

To design this, I would allow Menu to have a submenu prop.

This allows your menu to be recursive.

```js
interface MenuData {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    submenu?: MenuData;
};


const Menu = (props: MenuData) => {
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            {props.submenu &&
                <Menu
                    id={props.submenu.id}
                    name={props.submenu.name}
                    submenu={props.submenu.submenu}
                />
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```